# How to get a rough estimate of my GPAs for UK Ph.D admissions

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, gpa, india

I have an Indian bachelor's degree from a tier 3 college 8.04/10, First class with distinction, and a 3.33/4 from Rutgers University Masters in CS.

I know most of the UK colleges have something called a 2:1 honor system? I found various websites explaining what that means, but I still don't understand what it actually is. Do my GPAs qualify as a 2:1 honor?

I don't have any publications and at this point, I am actually aiming for a 10 to 20 ranked university in the UK for a CS Ph.D. in Robotics.

Comment: Most UK universities will take care of this if you send them your transcript.

Comment: "2:1 honors system" is not a thing. A 2:1 (second class, upper division) is one of four degree classifications you can get, which are based on percentages (see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_undergraduate_degree_classification). Whether you get honours or not depends on the university: at mine you just had to not fail any courses and you automatically got an honours degree. So you can't translate your grades to honours or not as that comes from your own university. As user1271772 says, the university you're applying to will take care of the grade conversion itself.